# Estimating standard Gibbs free energy of a molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, conformers

In order to estimate the standard Gibbs free energy of a molecule at room temperature and normal pressure, we use Maxwell Boltzmann average over  rotational conformers.

**Question**

Should we consider cis/trans isomers besides rotational conformers? Is there any criterion for it?

Comment: Why, it's simple: those species which are there can contribute. Those which aren't, can't. Suppose you have a _cis_ isomer; does it convert to _trans_ at room temperature? No.

Comment: @IvanNeretin After a long time the two isomers trans/cis should equilibrate. So why we should no consider them?

Comment: @adosar Well, yeah, they will, but not before hell freezes over, so for all practical purposes we may safely assume they won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to calculate the partition functions for each type of motion and then calculate the thermodynamic quantities from these.

As to internal rotation, if the energy for this is far greater than $k_BT$, such as with a C=C bond, then treat it as a torsion and use this frequency. If the barrier to rotation is small compared to $k_BT$ then treat it as a free rotor but reduce the partition function by *n* if there are *n* barriers. In the intermediate case you will have to find the barrier (say by spectroscopy) and fit the data to a model of the potential (usually of a cosine form)and then numerically solving the Schrodinger eqn. to find energy levels.

If your temperature is so high that cis-trans reaction occurs then you should probably have to treat this as a mixture.